# EXCEL: This file has more than xxxx records

Tags: excel

I am trying to open a file that i exported from TOAD which has 1.4 million records. It has 4 columns.

I tried opening the file in notepad++, deleting half records there and copying them into other file and saving them. But when i open the 2 files in excel, all the columns are combined as one column.

Could someone give me a solution on how to divide the 1.4million records excel file into 2 files without messing up the columns or data.

Comment: Wind it back a little - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want the first 2 columns in the first file and the second 2 columns  in the second file ??

Comment: no i want all the columns in both the files. Its just when i open the file excel is not completely opening the file so i want to split the whole file into two

Comment: How many records do you want in each file ??

Comment: Is the file xls, xlsx or csv? And which operating system?

Comment: Which character is the column separator ??

Comment: CSV, delimited text, comma saperated - this is what i used when i exported the file from TOAD.

I am using windows 10

Comment: Try opening it with Wordpad. It may open, though it will not be in columns. You may try one of the text file splitter programs; many are available.

Comment: @rnso but columns are important. if i dont need columns, the notepad++ method i mentioned in the post worked just fine.

Comment: Try Libreoffice. It may work. Other options may be there if you can specify what exactly you need to do with columns. You may also try splitting that one column into original 4 depending on the format.

Comment: @rnso this report has account balances and stuff. i am sending this to my boss and he uses excel. i used other software before but i want to see if there is any possible way i could do this in excel.

Comment: Try splitting that one column into 4 columns. There are several options in menu for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132222/discussion-between-sai-avinash-and-rnso).

Answer (score 2):

If you are married to Excel, skip Toad completely and bring the data in directly with MS Query.

If this isn't SQL Server, you will need to set up an ODBC connection, and from there you can bind the query to the spreadsheet as follows:

1. From the "Data" tab, select "From Other Sources"
2. Pick SQL Server if it's SQL Server or MS Query if it's anything else
3. Skip all of the menus and paste in your SQL once you get to MS Query
4. Close MS Query, and your live query (and its results) will be dynamically linked to an Excel table (aka ListObject)

[image]

[image]

[image]

The great thing about this is when you want to refresh the query, right-click and refresh.  Done.

Better still, you can set up the ODBC connection for your boss and he can do it himself.

Oh, and if you want this split into two datasets, change your SQL to pull the first half and the second half and have them each in a different worksheet.  How you do this depends on your DBMS, which I'd encourage you to tag in your question.